# Swift 4: Unexpectedly found nil when attempting add label to a custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Mu code unwraps nil when I attempt to add the label as a subview to my cell class (addSubview(nameLabel)).  I have dragged the reference to the nameLabel from the storyboard. In the story board, this cell is linked to the myCell class. I have done this exact process for a different cell in a different table, and it still works without errors. What could I be missing ?

```
 class myCell: UITableViewCell {

    var myTableViewController: myViewController?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!

    func setupViews() {

        addSubview(nameLabel)

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": nameLabel]))  
    }  
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the cell instance?  The fact that you are adding the subview manually tells me that you aren't getting the cell instance from the storyboard prototype since that would add the subview for you. Since you aren't getting the cell from the storyboard, you can't expect the outlets to be bound

Comment: Which line exactly is crashing?

Comment: addSubview(nameLabel). If commented out, the first reference to the nameLabel after its declaration.

Comment: let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
        
       cell.myNameLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].name

Comment: Make sure that you call `cell.awakeFromNib()` directly after creating it (before accessing any properties, especially `IBOutlet`s).

Comment: Idea 1: Search your code for a line of code where you say `register(myCell` to the table view. If you find it, delete that line.

Comment: Idea 2: Why aren't you calling `setupViews` in your `init?(coder`??? You need to call it under all circumstances, don't you? If you're dequeuing the cell from the storyboard, isn't `init?(coder:` the one that gets called? Easy to find out with a breakpoint or a `print` statement of course.

Comment: BTW, you don't want a strong reference back to your table view controller in your cell. Make sure to make that `weak`.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this wrong. Set up a custom cell type as a prototype for your table view, and add the custom views/labels there. Wire them up to outlets in your storyboard. When you do that, you don't need custom code to create your labels. The storyboard will do it for you.

If you insist on creating your labels in code, you actually need to create and configure the label. Your current code has `nameLabel` set up as an implicitly unwrapped optional, but nowhere do you create a label. Your setupLabels code attempts to add `nameLabel` as a subview even though it's nil, and THAT is why you are crashing:

```
func setupViews() {

    nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero) //This is what's missing
    addSubview(nameLabel) //This line does not create a label object.

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", 
      options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), 
      metrics: nil, 
      views: ["v0": nameLabel]))  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call setupViews() method from cellForRowAtIndexPath like this way

```
cell.setupViews()
```